# Python - How to extract only list name inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a json file with nested dict and inside the dict nested lists. How can I display all the dict names?
I have no experience with python so I have no idea.
This is what I have done so far:

```
import json


def show_all_teams():
   
    teamsData = open("scores_db.json")
    all_data = teamsData.read()
    listAll = json.loads(all_data)

    for teams in listAll['football']:
        print(teams)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    show_all_teams()
```

But this shows me everything inside football. I am trying to display only the three name teams (Green Bay Packers, Kansas City Chiefs, Tampa Bay Buccaneers)

My json file looks something like this:

```
    {
  "football": [
    {
      "Green Bay Packers": [
        {
          "week": "19-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101160gnb",
          "away_name": "Los Angeles Rams",
          "away_abbr": "ram",
          "away_score": 18,
          "home_name": "Green Bay Packers",
          "home_abbr": "gnb",
          "home_score": 32,
          "winning_name": "Green Bay Packers",
          "winning_abbr": "gnb",
          "losing_name": "Los Angeles Rams",
          "losing_abbr": "ram"
        },
        {
          "week": "20-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101240gnb",
          "away_name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
          "away_abbr": "tam",
          "away_score": 31,
          "home_name": "Green Bay Packers",
          "home_abbr": "gnb",
          "home_score": 26,
          "winning_name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
          "winning_abbr": "tam",
          "losing_name": "Green Bay Packers",
          "losing_abbr": "gnb"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Kansas City Chiefs": [
        {
          "week": "17-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101030kan",
          "away_name": "Los Angeles Chargers",
          "away_abbr": "sdg",
          "away_score": 38,
          "home_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "home_abbr": "kan",
          "home_score": 21,
          "winning_name": "Los Angeles Chargers",
          "winning_abbr": "sdg",
          "losing_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "losing_abbr": "kan"
        },
        {
          "week": "19-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101170kan",
          "away_name": "Cleveland Browns",
          "away_abbr": "cle",
          "away_score": 17,
          "home_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "home_abbr": "kan",
          "home_score": 22,
          "winning_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "winning_abbr": "kan",
          "losing_name": "Cleveland Browns",
          "losing_abbr": "cle"
        },
        {
          "week": "19-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101240kan",
          "away_name": "Buffalo Bills",
          "away_abbr": "buf",
          "away_score": 24,
          "home_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "home_abbr": "kan",
          "home_score": 38,
          "winning_name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
          "winning_abbr": "kan",
          "losing_name": "Buffalo Bills",
          "losing_abbr": "buf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Tampa Bay Buccaneers": [
        {
          "week": "17-2020",
          "boxscore": "202101030tam",
          "away_name": "Atlanta Falcons",
          "away_abbr": "atl",
          "away_score": 27,
          "home_name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
          "home_abbr": "tam",
          "home_score": 44,
          "winning_name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
          "winning_abbr": "tam",
          "losing_name": "Atlanta Falcons",
          "losing_abbr": "atl"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the dictionaries keys.

```
import json


def show_all_teams():
   
    teamsData = open("scores_db.json")
    all_data = teamsData.read()
    listAll = json.loads(all_data)

    for teams in listAll['football']:
        print(list(teams.keys()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    show_all_teams()
```

**output**

```
['Green Bay Packers']
['Kansas City Chiefs']
['Tampa Bay Buccaneers']
```

---

**changed line**

This line here gets the keys of the dictionaries.

```
print(teams.keys())
```

**output**

```
dict_keys(['Green Bay Packers'])
dict_keys(['Kansas City Chiefs'])
dict_keys(['Tampa Bay Buccaneers'])
```

I am using `list(teams.keys())` just to make it more accessible because you and iterate through it and print it as a string.

Comment: But now how do you loop through the values inside each team?
Do you know a good tutorial that explains how to get each different value?

Comment: I would look here. https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this:
`print(list(teams.keys()))`

Answer (score -1):

```
import json


def show_all_teams():
   
    teamsData = open("scores_db.json")
    all_data = teamsData.read()
    listAll = json.loads(all_data)

    for teams in listAll['football'].keys():
        print(teams)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    show_all_teams()
```

this is the right way to get your desired output. What I have done is I have used the keys() function of dictionary in the for loop

```
for teams in listAll['football'].keys()
```

this helps you get all the keys of a dictionary.
Hope my answer helps you.